How might someone with a background in group theory start research into topos theory?
The Question:

How might an early career mathematician with a background of research in group theory start research into topos theory?

I want links between the two areas, not career advice, though it would be welcome.
Context:
Here is a search on MSE of all my topos theory posts. This is particularly relevant.
Thoughts:
In private conversation (via email) with Dr. Caramello, she stated:

Grothendieck toposes are generalisations of discrete groups, and can also be constructed from topological and localic groups, or, more generally, groupoids. There is a lot of research to do on the relationship between group-theoretic properties and topos-theoretic invariants, i.e. on understanding how fundamental notions or results in group theory could be understood in terms of topos-theoretic constructions involving the corresponding toposes.

That's all well & good, but where does one start? What does the literature say? What is the most accessible starting point?
Also, I don't want to limit this to Grothendiek topoi. Elementary topoi are fun too!

I have some knowledge about both group theory and (really 80s state of the art) topos theory; I have no clue how to make ANY sense out of your quote. If anything, topos is a generalized category of G-sets. Overall those vague remarks that "X could be understood in terms of topos theory" hinge on a crucial but usually omitted detail: you know diddly squat about your topos until you understand the site really well; and analysis of the possible sites is what group theory really does.

In a similar vein one could argue that the locally presentable categories are generalisation of a group. Result is still the same: nothing. Topoi are more fashionable than locally presentable categories, so people usually try to sell them as a cure-all. Also you can replace "Grothendieck toposes" in the quote with, for example, infinity-categories (here I'm at least confident that comparison with discrete group makes sense); it will be the same vacuosly true, slightly intriguing (for some readers) platitude.

Start by learning the basics, particularly of category theory, and then topos theory?  McLarty's book might be a good place. Then Mac Lane and Moerdijk. I say this in all honesty.
